# How to tell if a waiting Service Worker is ready?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, service-worker-events

[According to the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerRegistration/waiting), the `ServiceWorker.waiting` property returns a reference to a service worker that is installed and waiting to be activated.

This is fine. But how do I find out when the waiting service worker has transitioned to a new state?

The service worker returned by `ServiceWorker.waiting` does not seem to have any of the necessary events for notifying state change:

```
if (registration.waiting) {

  registration.waiting.postMessage('skip-waiting');

  // This is failing because ready is undefined.
  registration.waiting.ready.then(function () {

    console.log('new service worker - ready');
 }
}
```

Comment: Waiting is a property on the *registration*, not the worker. Once you have the worker, it doesn't have the waiting property; it has a state and [`onstatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/onstatechange).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, I think you have the answer there. I already tried `registration.waiting.onstatechange` which is undefined. However, `registration.waiting.addEventListener('statechange`...)` works, although for some reason fires twice (in both Chrome and FireFox). Thanks, please post as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, `registration.waiting.onstatechange` is null in Chrome. However, the following works:

```
if (registration.waiting) {

  const waiting = registration.waiting;

  waiting.postMessage('skip-waiting');

  waiting.addEventListener('statechange', function (e) {

    if(waiting.state === 'activated') {
      console.log('new service worker - ready');
    }
 }
}
```